# Proof explanation (Complete subspace)

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, complete-spaces, sequence-of-function

While studying functional analysis, **more specifically** that the subspace $Y=\{x \in \mathcal{C}[a, b] \mid x(a)=x(b)\} \subset \mathcal{C}[a, b]$ is complete, I came across a very simple question I cannot seem to answer, and I am afraid I am missing something simple here.

To show that the limit of the sequence, which is described in the related link, belongs to $Y$, one should show that $x(a)=x(b)$. **But why is that enough? Shouldn't one also show the limit of the sequence belongs to $\mathcal{C}[a, b]$?** In my opinion this is missing, since it is also a requirement for $x$ to belong to $Y$.

Thanks in advance, Lucas

**Related:**
[Show that the subspace $Y = \{ x \in \mathcal{C}[a,b] \mid x(a) = x(b) \} \subset \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698310/show-that-the-subspace-y-x-in-mathcalca-b-mid-xa-xb-subse)

Comment: Notice that such a cauchy sequence in Y would also be a cauchy sequence in C[a,b], which is complete, so it has a limit in C[a,b].

Comment: Yes, you need to establish that the limit is in $C[a,b]$ but presumably this is in the context of knowing that $C[a,b]$ is complete?

Comment: @copper.hat How would you state that in the proof? "Since the sequence is in a subspace of $C[a, b]$ and we know this space is complete, the limit has to lie in $C[a, b]$, establishing $x$ is also a continuous function". Is that ok?

Comment: @RichardJensen But how the cauchy sequences appeared here? I am confused

Comment: @Lucas I would say that since $C[a,b]$ is complete, the sequence had a limit which is continuous. Since convergence is uniform, it is also pointwise and so $x(a) = x(b)$ since $x_n(a) = x_n(b)$ for all $n$.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you know how to explain the convergence is uniform? As José carlos wrote, it has to do with the sup norm, but I would not know how to precisely argue

Comment: Since $\|x\| = \max_{t \in [a,b]} |x(t)|$ you must have $|x(t)| \le \|x\|$ for any $t \in [a,b]$.

Comment: Finally, got it! Nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ with respect to the $\sup$ norm is the same thing as asserting that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $x$. And uniform convergence preserves continuity.

Comment: Why is this true exactly? I am little bit confused. Everytime one uses the sup norm this will imply uniform convergence in the space?

Comment: It doesn't simply *imply* it. [They are equivalent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525649/sup-norm-and-uniform-convergence)